# grep from x GB onwards

Tags: macos, grep, filesize

I want to [recover a deleted file](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337026/recovering-a-deleted-file-on-macos) that contains the word "foo". On macOS, [it is not possible to `grep` a partition](https://superuser.com/a/773974) so I `grep` the whole disk:

```
sudo grep -a -B 20 -A 20 "foo" /dev/disk0
```

The command executes when I [disable System Integrity Protection](https://superuser.com/a/978398), but after reading close to 30 GB (according to the Activity Monitor) of my 1 TB hard drive [the process is killed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/355869/grep-command-is-killed).

**How do I begin a new search 29 GB into the hard drive?**

Or in other words: How do I begin a `grep` search a specified number of bytes into a file from its beginning?

---

macOS 10.13.6

Comment: With `dd` and `seek/skip`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Like this: `sudo dd if=/dev/disk0 bs=1GB count=5 skip=29 | grep -a -B 20 -A 20 "foo"` ?

Comment: Nearly, but that will only search gigabytes 29 through 34 because of your `count=5`

Comment: @MarkSetchell That's what I want. If I don't specify an end before `grep` get's killed, I won't know how far it got and where to start the next search. I just accidentally watched the activity monitor the moment `grep` disappeared from it, leaving no trace of its progress.

Comment: Btw, it has to be `bs=1g` (at least on macOS).